# Radio buttons are not getting checked for two separate questions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have made 2 questions in a form using Bootstrap. The first question has 4 options and the second question has 4 options. When I check one of the options from the first question and then if I check one of the options from the second question then the radio button checked in the first question becomes unchecked. Why are the checkboxes dependent on two different questions?

index.html:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <h3>[Test]Contact us Survey Form</h3>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div id="agegroup">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <h4>What is your age group?</h4>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> >=25 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> 26-35 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> 36-50 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> >50 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <h4>What is your gender?</h4>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> Female</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> Male</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"/> Prefer not to say</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</form>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why down  votes ?

Comment: _A radio **group is defined** by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same `name`._ ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)) I retracted my DV, but it was for the reason of not reading the documentation fisrt

Comment: This happens because all your radio buttons have same name. Use checkbox instead

Comment: @JavaEvgen Can you answer it so that I can upvote.

Comment: @AlonEitan Can you answer it so that I can upvote

Comment: @waterman That's fine :) You can accept the current answer which is correct

Comment: @AlonEitan I will always read docs from now on I mostly don't follow MDN docs I search on w3schools for CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give each group a different name.

So, if you use `name="optradio"` for the first group, give the second group something like `name="optradio2"`.